# Uninstalling .Net 4.5

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, .net-4.0, rollback

I have a question. Server is running Windows Server 2008 R2. Originally had Microsoft .Net4.0 installed on it and I had to upgrade it to 4.5. Now due to some issues I have to uninstall it.
My question is, if I will uninstall 4.5 would it automatically roll back to 4.0?
4.0?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a rollback, .NET framework versions are side-by-side installs.  Installing 4.5 doesn't overwrite 4.0, it's in addition.

In other words, uninstalling 4.5 will not break 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Found this looking for info about rolling back server 2012 from .net 4.5 to 4.0.

The comment that says uninstalling 4.5 won't break 4.0 is wrong. In my environment, one app and one website do not work if .net 4.5 is installed. Unchecking it in Roles and Features doesn't help as that disables both 4.0 and 4.5. It has to be uninstalled. We also have 4.5 blocked in the WSUS server so it doesn't auto-install since MS put it in the important update list.

On every pc we do this on, we have to go back and reinstall 4.0. They may be side-by-side installations, but removing 4.5 definitely breaks 4.0.